# Application Shortcut for Slack does not work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, preferences, slack

I've created an application shortcut for the "All Unreads" command in Slack to change from <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of the Application Shortcuts]

It shows up in the toolbar for Slack:

[image: Screenshot of the Slack toolbar]

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Slack, I see the "Go" toolbar header light up, but nothing happens. This is true for other toolbar entries in Slack as well, such as "Switch to Channel". How can I get application-specific shortcuts to work?

Clicking the toolbar entry manually works, but it seems that activating it with a shortcut does not.

Comment: Maybe the keyboard shortcut is conflicting with another one?

Comment: It doesn't conflict with any shortcut I can see, and I've tried different shortcut keys to no avail.